# Delete Media not attached with Any posts

Tags: plugins, media

Hello Please let me know how can I remove all media present in my media folder that is not assigned to any posts in my wordpress. I need this things to be done with the help of custom code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this direclty from your WordPress Dashboard. Login to your website and go to media for the same.

In the media, select list view and filter the media which are Unattached to the post. Once you get the filtered media items, select all items and delete the same using Bulk Actions.

The same thing is also shown in below attached image.
[image: Unattached Media in WordPress]

Comment: Kaustubh thanks for the reply. Actually I am finding the way the above thing can be done Programmatically. I will upvote your answer as you are right but this thing is not possible in my case